# Rotate an excluded mask-image in css

Tags: html, css

I have a mask-image in CSS that I can easily position with the mask-position property, but I can't figure out how to rotate it. How can I rotate the mask-image without rotating the entire element?

Here is my code:

```html
<body>
  <div class="water light-layer"></div>
</body>


<style lang="scss">
  .light-layer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100rem;
    margin-top: -2.55rem;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(53, 99, 233, 0.98) 1.17%, rgba(25, 53, 136, 0.99) 36.14%, #000D34 96.66%);
    mask-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/FzmCjLL/Jqtz.png"), linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-composite: exclude;
    mask-position: 50% 20%;
    /* Rotate here */
  }
</style>
```

I've tried using normal css rotate but that rotates the entire element.

Comment: you want an animation?

Comment: @TemaniAfif i want a way to controllably rotate the mask-image, that could be via css, javascript or any other methods. It does not have to be an animation.

Comment: in the answer you accepted, the mask no more apply, you don't have transparency.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah i discovered this after i accepted. So i'm still looking for a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself using svg mask and transform. Took me a good while. Here is the code sandbox i created:
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/busy-voice-fclkyp?file=%2Findex.html%3A14%2C15&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0006356qvj4lx5t2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0002356qy5rpy5bp%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0003356qsel8xavy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0005356qmoej01re%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrb0hosp0002356qy5rpy5bp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0002356qy5rpy5bp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0i3oe0055356ql7o27txu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A2%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A2%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb10yac0002356qw27ot7zi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A15%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A15%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrb10yac0002356qw27ot7zi%2522%257D%252C%2522clrb0hosp0005356qmoej01re%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0004356qfiznqmu6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0005356qmoej01re%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0004356qfiznqmu6%2522%257D%252C%2522clrb0hosp0003356qsel8xavy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrb0hosp0003356qsel8xavy%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to rotate the mask image without rotating the background is to separate the mask image and background to different elements. Here is the changed code:

```html
<body>
    <div class="water">
        <div class="light-layer"></div>
    </div>
</body>


<style lang="scss">
    .water {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100rem;
        margin-top: -2.55rem;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(53, 99, 233, 0.98) 1.17%, rgba(25, 53, 136, 0.99) 36.14%, #000D34 96.66%);
    }
    .light-layer {
        height: 100%;
        background: white;
        mask-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/FzmCjLL/Jqtz.png");
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        mask-composite: exclude;
        mask-position: 50% 20%;
        transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I thought this worked at first, but I discovered that the light-layer is only a white star that covers the water and does not mask it.